# I can start xdebug if trigger string is present, but how do I have it start *only* if the trigger string is present?

Tags: xdebug

I'm trying to only start an xdebug session *only* when I pass a certain trigger string with the request via a cookie, like so:

```
GET https://1.2.3.4
cookie: XDEBUG_TRIGGER=mytriggerstring
```

Although I can get xdebug to start as planned with the trigger, I can also still start the session without the trigger using this generic request:

```
GET https://1.2.3.4?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=anything
```

Here's my complete xdebug config file:

```
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.trigger_value=mytriggerstring
xdebug.client_host = 192.168.1.10
```

The xdebug docs [here](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#start_with_request) say

> The functionality only gets activated when a specific trigger is
> present when the request starts

I'm not seeing anything there that says XDEBUG_SESSION_START has to be disabled, or how to disable it if that was needed.

What am I missing?

This is on CentOS 7 and here's my xdebug/php version:

```
PHP 7.4.27 (cli) (built: Dec 14 2021 17:17:06) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

Here are logs from xdebug.log_level=10:

..passing no xdebug params:

```
[661] Log opened at 2022-02-24 02:40:03.415677
[661] [Config] DEBUG: Checking if trigger 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' is enabled for mode 'debug'
[661] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' not found, falling back to 'XDEBUG_SESSION'
[661] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_SESSION' not found, so not activating
[661] Log closed at 2022-02-24 02:40:03.416915
```

..passing my trigger via the cookie:

```
[663] Log opened at 2022-02-24 02:40:38.079079
[663] [Config] DEBUG: Checking if trigger 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' is enabled for mode 'debug'
[663] [Config] DEBUG: The trigger value 'mytriggerstring' matched the shared secret 'mytriggerstring' for mode 'debug'
[663] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 192.168.1.10:9003.
[663] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 192.168.1.10:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
```

..passing the XDEBUG_SESSION_START=anything cgi param

```
[661] Log opened at 2022-02-24 02:42:39.009885
[661] [Step Debug] DEBUG: Found 'XDEBUG_SESSION_START' HTTP variable, with value 'anything'
[661] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 192.168.1.10:9003.
[661] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 192.168.1.10:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
```

Comment: "Although I can get xdebug to start as planned with the trigger, I can also still start the session without the trigger using this generic request" — that should not be the case. Can you make a log file? Use xdebug.log_level=10 and xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log — it should tell you exactly how Xdebug decided to initiate a debugging session.

Comment: I added that to the post, should have thought of that.  I only added the first few lines, which seemed to say why it connected, as all the rest didn't seem to apply to why the connection was made (a bazillion breakpoints throughout my code mainly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations! You have found a bug, I think.

Would you please be so kind to report it to the Xdebug development team at https://bugs.xdebug.org ? Just copying and pasting the whole information from this post their issue tracker will likely be enough for them to fix this (if it turns out to be a real bug).

Comment: I did so thank you https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=2068  We'll see if they can reproduce.  Still seems likely I could be missing something still though, so looking forward to seeing what they find. Thnks again!

Comment: I'm sure I can ;-)

Comment: haha oh yea, by them looks like I mean you...  you rock thanks for making this software, has made my life easier for a long time!

Comment: Having a look now!

Comment: FWIW, this is now fixed: https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/pull/825